# Create a new dataframe of two features from df with many, where rows conditioned on one feature

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to check normality for eight groups of features(Region_1, Region_2...etc) and need to create a new df for each; the new df would have two columns, one for "Quantity" and the other for the Region .  I have one-hot-encoded the features so, need each new df to be "Quantity" and "Region_x" where row for "Region_x" has a 1.  I've tried many ways to include more of the table from jupyter, to no avail.  Please let me know if you need more information to help solve this.

```
Quantity    Region_0    Region_1    Region_2    Region_3    Region_4    Region_5    Region_6    Region_7    Region_8
```

I've tried variations of placing a condition on the same line where I've defined the new df.

`r0df = copy.deepcopy(q2df[["Quantity", "Region_0" =="1"]])`

KeyError: '[False] not in index'

I need the result to be a new dataframe with "Quantity" and a Region, where the observations are only the rows in Region that have a 1.

(this code snippet is just to give a better example of the table i'm working with in python; I used this tool: https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Region_1</th><th>Region_2</th><th>Region_3</th></tr><tr><td>45</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>36</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>40</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can create a dict of dataframes like:

```
m=df.set_index('Quantity')
n=m[m.eq(1)]
d={'df_'+str(i):n[i].dropna().to_frame() for i in n.columns}
```

---

**Output:**

```
{'df_Region_1':           Region_1
 Quantity          
 36             1.0
 30             1.0, 'df_Region_2':           Region_2
 Quantity          
 45             1.0
 36             1.0
 40             1.0, 'df_Region_3':           Region_3
 Quantity          
 45             1.0
 36             1.0
 40             1.0}
```

Then you can call each key of the dictionary to see the df, example:

```
print(d['df_Region_1'])
```

---

```
          Region_1
Quantity          
36             1.0
30             1.0
```

Comment: thanks anky_91!  I have that working but having trouble getting the new df to return observations where value in Region column == 1.

this returns True or False for each row `r0df = d["df_Region_0"]["Region_0"] ==1`,  and I think I can then filter that, but I was hoping to do everything in one line.  Maybe I need to turn this into a function

Comment: I added a code snipped above that you can run and then outputs a legible table

Comment: @Donum i have edited the code. Hope it helps now.. :)

Comment: thank you @anky_91!  It works, I appreciate the help!